# Intermediate Value Theorem in point-set topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Theorem: Let $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous map, where $X$ is a connected space and Y is an ordered set in the order topology. If $a,b \in X$ and $r \in Y$ such that $f(a) \lt r \lt f(b)$, then $\exists c \in X (f(c)=r)$

Proof Attempt: Let $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous map where $X$ is a connected space and $Y$ is an ordered set under the order topology. Suppose $a,b \in X$ and $r \in Y$ such that $f(a) \lt r \lt f(b)$. Since $X$ is connected then $f(X)$ is connected. Let $f(X)=(\gamma_0, \gamma)\cup (\overline{\gamma},\gamma')$. Since $f(a),f(b) \in f(X) \subset Y$, then $f(a),f(b)\in (\gamma_0, \gamma)\cup (\overline{\gamma},\gamma')$, then, w.l.o.g., let $f(b)\in (\overline{\gamma},\gamma')$, and $f(a)\in (\overline{\gamma},\gamma')$. Also, $f(X)$ is connected so $(\gamma_0,\gamma)\cap (\gamma,\gamma')\neq\emptyset$. This forces $r\in(\gamma_0,\gamma)\cup (\overline{\gamma},\gamma')=f(X)$. Therefore, $r\in f(X)$ and $\exists c\in X(f(c)=r)$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want the proof I wrote to be verified.

Comment: Could you at least let us know what you are proving? Please give the complete statement.

Comment: I have added the theorem's statement. Thanks.

Comment: why is $f[X]$ of that form? I see no justification. Just a lot of useless $\gamma$'s I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better: suppose we have $(Y,<)$ in the order topology and $f: X \to Y$ continuous with $X$ connected and for some points $a,b \in X$ we have $f(a) < r < f(b)$ with $r \in Y$.

Suppose there is no $x \in X$ with $f(x)=r$.

Then define $O_1=\{y \in Y: y < r \}$ and $O_2=\{y \in Y: y > r\}$ which are open in $Y$ in the order topology.

Firstly $$f^{-1}[O_1] \cup f^{-1}[O_2] = X$$

because we assumed $r$ is not assumed as a value, and $Y$ has a linear order, so always $f(x) > r$ or $f(x) < r$ must hold, but not both, so the sets are disjoint. We also know that $a \in f^{-1}[O_1]$ and $b \in f^{-1}[O_2]$, so both these sets are open (by continity of $f$), disjoint, non-empty and cover $X$. This is a contradiction with the connectedness of $X$. So we must have some $x$ with $f(x)=r$.

Comment: I initially thought of starting with the $f^{-1}[O_1]$ and $f^{-1}[O_2]$ like how you have defined it. But I think that would make $f(X)$ not connected, since $X$ is connected, would it not?

Comment: @TheLastCipher it doesn’t matter really if we get a contradiction from $X$ connected or $f[X]$ connected. The eventual idea will be the same.

Comment: I don't understand why it would not matter, especially when we use it as our starting assumption. :(

Comment: @TheLastCipher I chose to use the assumption "$X$ connected" directly. $O_1$ and $O_2$ form a direct disconnection of $f[X]$ which also gives a contradiction with a known theorem. Both are OK. My proof can be seen as a partial reproof of $X$ connected implies $f[X]$ connected in a way.

Comment: ahh yes. It's the contrapositive. Thanks!

Comment: @TheLastCipher Glad to help. We just pull back the disconnection of $f[X]$ to $X$ via $f$, same as in that proof.